# Load testing with Cucumber and Java

Tags: cucumber-junit

I need to perform load testing for my REST web service using Cucumber and Java. This REST web service accepts one input which is a String called id and returns complex JSON object.

I wrote a .feature file with Given, When and Then annotations which are defined in java.
The skeleton definition of the class and annotations are here under.

## 1) Feature  (UserActivity.feature)

```
@functional @integration
Feature: User System Load Test
        Scenario Outline: Load test for user data summary from third party UserSystem
                            Given Simultaneously multiple users are hitting XYZ services with an id=<ids>
                            When I invoke third party link with above id for multiple users simultaneously
                            Then I should get response code and response message for all users
                            Examples:
                                | ids |
                                | "pABC123rmqst" |
                                | "fakXYZ321rmv" |
                                | "bncMG4218jst" |
```

## 2) LoadTestStepDef.java (Feature definition)

```
package com.system.test.cucumber.steps;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;

import com.system.test.restassured.LoadTestUtil;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;


public class LoadTestStepDef 
{

    private static Logger LOG       = LogManager.getLogger( LoadTestStepDef.class );
    private String        id        = null;
    private LoadTestUtil service    = null;

    @Given("^Simultaneously multiple users are hitting XYZ services with an a id=\"(.*?)\"$" )
    public void Simultaneously_multiple_users_are_hitting_XYZ_services_with_a_id( String id )
    {
        LOG.debug( "ID {}", id );
        LOG.info( "ID {}", id );
        this.id = id;
    }

    @When( "^I invoke third party link with above id for multiple users simultaneously$" )
    public void invoke_third_party_link_With_Above_ID_for_multiple_users_simultaneously() throws InitializationError
    {
        LOG.debug( " *** Calling simulatenously {} ", id );
        LOG.info( " *** Calling simulatenously {}", id );

        //Create object of service
        service = new LoadTestUtil();

        //Set the id to the created service and invoke method

        service.setData(id);
        service.invokeSimultaneosCalls(10);

    }


    @Then( "^I should get response code and response message for all users$" )
    public void Should_get_response_code_and_response_message_for_all_users()
    {
        LOG.info( "*** Assert for response Code" );
        service.assertHeaderResponseCodeAndMessage();
    }
}
```

## 3) LoadTestUtil.java

```
package com.system.test.restassured;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import com.jayway.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class LoadTestUtil 
{


        private String id = null;
        private int numberofTimes;

        //Create List to hold all Future<Long> 
        private List<JsonPath> jsonResponseList = new ArrayList<JsonPath>();

        //No arg Constructor
        public LoadTestUtil()
        {

        }

        //Set data method to set the initial id
        public void setData(String id)
        {
            LOG.info( "LoadTestUtil.setData()", id );
            this.id = id;
        }

        //This method is used call the REST webservice N times using threads and get response
        public void invokeSimultaneosCalls(int numberofTimes)
        {
            LOG.info( "LoadTestUtil.invokeSimultaneosCalls() - Start" );
            this.numberofTimes = numberofTimes;
            try
            {
                long start = System.nanoTime();



                int numberOfThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
                LOG.info("Number of processor available {}" , numberOfThreads);

                //Create pool for the Executor Service with numberOfThreads.
                ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);


                //Create a list to hold the Future object associated with Callable
                List<Future<JsonPath>> futureList = new ArrayList<Future<JsonPath>>();

                //Create new RESTServiceCallTask instance
                Callable<JsonPath> callable = new RESTServiceCallTask(id);

                Future<JsonPath> future = null;

                //Iterate N number of times to submit the callable object
                for(int count=1; count<=numberofTimes;count++)
                {
                    //Submit Callable tasks to the executor
                    future = executor.submit(callable);
                    //Add Future to the list to get return value using Future
                    futureList.add(future);
                }

                //Create a flag to monitor the thread status. Check whether all worker threads are completed or not
                boolean threadStatus = true;
                while (threadStatus) 
                {
                    if (future.isDone()) 
                    {
                        threadStatus = false;
                        //Iterate the response obtained from the futureList
                        for(Future<JsonPath> futuree : futureList)
                        {
                            try 
                            {
                                //print the return value of Future, notice the output delay in console
                                // because Future.get() waits for task to get completed
                                JsonPath  response  = futuree.get();
                                jsonResponseList.add(response);
                            } 
                            catch(InterruptedException ie)
                            {
                                ie.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            catch(ExecutionException ee)
                            {
                                ee.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }//End of for to iterate the futuree list
                    } //End of future.isDone()
                } //End of while (threadStatus)

                //shut down the executor service now
                executor.shutdown();

                //Calculate the time taken by the threads for execution
                executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS); // or longer.    

                long time = System.nanoTime() - start;

                logger.info("Tasks took " + time/1e6 + " ms to run");

                long milliSeconds = time / 1000000;

                long seconds, minutes, hours;  
                seconds = milliSeconds / 1000;  
                hours = seconds / 3600;  
                seconds = seconds % 3600;  
                seconds = seconds / 60;  
                minutes = seconds % 60;  
                logger.info("Task took " +  hours + " hours, " + minutes + " minutes and " + seconds + " seconds to complete");
            } //End of try block
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            LOG.info("LoadTestUtil.invokeSimultaneosCalls() - jsonResponseList {} " , jsonResponseList);
            System.out.println("LoadTestUtil.invokeSimultaneosCalls() - jsonResponseList {} " + jsonResponseList);
            LOG.info( "*** LoadTestUtil.invokeSimultaneosCalls() - End" );

        }

        public void assertHeaderResponseCodeAndMessage(){

            //Number of response objects available
            int size = jsonResponseList.size();
            LOG.info("Number of REST service calls made = ", size);

            for(JsonPath jsonResponse : jsonResponseList)
            {
                String responseCode = jsonResponse.get( "header.response_code").toString();
                String responseMessage = jsonResponse.get( "header.response_message").toString();

                assertEquals( "200", responseCode);
            assertEquals( "success", responseMessage);

            }
        }
}
```

## 4) RESTServiceCallTask.java

This class implements Callable and override the call() method.
In the call() method, the response in the form of JsonPath is returned for each call

```
package com.system.test.restassured;


import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.basePath;
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.baseURI;
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.port;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;


import com.system.test.restassured.TestUtil;
import com.jayway.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import com.jayway.restassured.response.Response;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class RESTServiceCallTask implements Callable<JsonPath>
{

    private static Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(RESTServiceCallTask.class);
    private Response  response = null;

    private String id;

    private String environment;
    //private JsonPath jsonPath;

    /**
     * Constructor initializes the call to third party system
     * 
     * @param id
     */
    public RESTServiceCallTask(String id) 
    {

        LOG.info("In RESTServiceCallTask() constructor ");
        this.id = id;

        //Read the environment variable ENV to get the corresponding environment's REST URL to call
        this.environment = System.getProperty("ENV");
        baseURI = TestUtil.getbaseURL(environment);
        basePath = "/bluelink/tracker/member_summary";
        port = 80;
        LOG.info(" *** Environment : {}, URI: {} and Resource {} ", environment, baseURI, basePath);
    }

    //This method is called by the threads to fire the REST service and returns JSONPath for each execution
    @Override
    public JsonPath call() throws Exception
    {
        LOG.info(" *** In call() method ");

        try 
        {
              response = given().headers("id", this.id).log().all().get();
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
              LOG.error("System Internal Server Error", e);
        }


        String strResponse = this.response.asString();
        LOG.info("Response : {}", strResponse);

        JsonPath jsonResponse = new JsonPath(strResponse);
        return jsonResponse;
    }
}
```

## 5) TestUtil.java

This utility class is used to get the REST URL corresponding to the passed environment

```
package com.system.test.restassured;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class TestUtil 
{
    private static Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(TestUtil.class);
    private static final Map<String, String> ENVIRONMENT_MAP =  new HashMap<String, String>();

    static
    {
        ENVIRONMENT_MAP.put("LOCAL", "http://localhost:9080");
        ENVIRONMENT_MAP.put("ENV1", "http://localhost:9080");
        ENVIRONMENT_MAP.put("ENV2", "http://localhost:9080");
        ENVIRONMENT_MAP.put("ENV3", "http://localhost:9080");
    }

    public static String getbaseURL(String environment)
    {
        LOG.info("Environment value fetched = {}", environment);
            return ENVIRONMENT_MAP.get(environment);
    }   

}
```

The problem here is that the multi-threading feature is not getting executed.
I used the MavenSurefire Plugin and tried with parallel classes and methods.  In those cases also the above scenario doesn't work.

Does Cucumber support java multi-threading?  If so what is wrong with the above feature definition?

Note - The same task is performed with stand alone program and able to run for 10,000 times
using 4 threads without any issues.  However not able to run the above code for 2000 times using Maven.  With 2000 times, the system crashed abruptly.

I am using Rational Application Developer 8.5, Websphere Server 8.0 with Maven 3.x for the above setup.

Thanks for your response.

Comment: I recommend you fix up the code using Code Sample. This will make your question more readable.

Comment: Using executors inside a step running tests in parallel are two totally unrelated concepts, and it does not sound like one of them is actually your problem. You should include some more information like the package structure of your runner, step classes and feature files.

Comment: Better too much than too little information :) I guess you use the cucumber junit runner to execute the scenarios, is it in the same package as the rest of the code? By default it will only search for features in subpackages of its own package, but that can be changed with the `CucumberOptions` annotation.